# Rails 4 ActiveRecord, if record exists, use id, else create a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

When an employee is created, he is given a title. If the title is unique, the record saves normally. If the title is not unique, I want to find the existing title, and use that instead. I can't figure out how to do this in the create action.

employer.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :title, :class_name => :EmployeeTitle, :foreign_key => "employee_title_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :title
end
```

employer_title.rb

```
class EmployerTitle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :title do |title| %>
    <%= title.input :name, label: "Title" %>
<% end %>
```

employees_controller.rb

```
def create
  if EmployeeTitle.exists?(name: employee_params[:title_attributes][:name])
    # find title and use it?
  else
    @employee = current_user.employee.build(employee_params)
  end
  if @employee.save
    flash[:success] = "Employee #{@employee.title.name} created."
    redirect_to @employee
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Edit: Using first_or_create

```
def create
  EmployeeTitle.where(name: employee_params[:title_attributes][:name]).first_or_create do |title|
    @employee = current_user.employees.build(employee_params, :title => title)
  end
  if @employee.save
    flash[:success] = "Employee #{@employee.title.name} created."
    redirect_to @employee
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This makes the @employee go out of scope. Error: Undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass.

In addition, if I do this, won't the title be created regardless of whether the rest of the employee data is valid?

Using private method

employee.rb

```
  private
    def title_attributes=(attributes)
      self.title = EmployeeTitle.find_or_create_by_name(name: attributes[:name])
    end
```

The value is not being set. I get a "cannot be blank" validation error. The parameters include

```
employee: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  title: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    name: Consultant
```

The !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess was not there before.

employee_params

```
  private
    def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(
          title_attributes: [:id, :name],
      )
    end
```

Comment: If `EmployeeTitle` exists with the a `name` then you need use that as an association instead of creating new, is that right?

Comment: i guess this is what youre looking for 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create

Comment: @User089247 Yes, the employee table has a employee_title_id. If the title exists, I want to use the id of that title. If it doesn't, I want to create a EmployeeTitle and use its id.

Comment: @amalrikmaia that might just be the answer. Let me try it.

Comment: @amalrikmaia I've edited my question. I tried your suggestion. It's close, but it's not doing exactly what I want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to change this:

```
def create
  if EmployeeTitle.exists?(name: employee_params[:title_attributes][:name])
    # find title and use it?
  else
    @employee = current_user.employee.build(employee_params)
  end
  if @employee.save
    flash[:success] = "Employee #{@employee.title.name} created."
    redirect_to @employee
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

with this:

```
def create
  @employee = current_user.employee.build(employee_params)
  if @employee.save
    flash[:success] = "Employee #{@employee.title.name} created."
    redirect_to @employee
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Now, override `title_attributes` method by putting this code in your *app/models/employee.rb* file:

```
def title_attributes=(attributes)
  self.title = EmployeeTitle.find_or_create_by_name(attributes[:name])
end
```

Now, every time you'll create an employee whose name already exists with the particular name, it'll be used by default for associating it as `title`. Let the controller be *skinny* as it used to be.

Read more about [`find_or_create_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) method here.

However, your question's title says: Rails 4, but you have tagged ruby-on-rails-3.2. If you're using Rails 4 then you can use this instead:

```
EmployeeTitle.find_or_create_by(name: attributes[:name])
```

Comment: Yes, I edited the create method. I posted the employee_params.

Comment: There is no stack trace. Basically, when I submit the form, the value for title is getting lost. The create action doesn't get the value, and the presence validator returns the form with an error saying, "Title can't be blank."

Comment: ok, do one thing: put this: `puts attributes.inspect` inside `title_attributes =(attributes)` method and see if it is a hash: `{name: 'Consultant' }`

Comment: It has something to do with the title_attributes method you defined. If I remove it, the form works (for unique values).

Comment: umm... not really.. I've had used such methods for couple of my applications and they works really well. You need to tell what exactly the error is. Hash should be as I mentioned in previous comment. Can you also post the parameters you see in rails server when you submit the form?

Comment: Ah, the console shows Unpermitted parameter: title. When I add the title_attributes method, the name of the parameter being passed changes from title_attributes to title, which is why it doesn't set the value. Why does this happen?

Comment: I am not sure, it's because probably you have not defined your form properly. parameters should be like: `{'employee' => {'title_attributes' => { 'name' => 'Consultant' },... } ` then only the above solution work. I am suspecting you have issues somewhere else. Fix the form first.

Comment: I'll figure that out and edit my question later. Thanks, your solution will work, I can see that. I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: After much trial-and-error, I figured out that it's working if I remove the private modifier from your method. Is the method supposed to be private?

Comment: @CuriousObserver : Sorry, you're right. that method should not be `private`. I have updated the answer accordingly.